# How to detect and quick a lua function taking too long to respond?

Tags: multithreading, lua, coronasdk, luasocket, lua-lanes

I'm using Corona SDK to make a simple app that requires luasocket.
Corona SDK support luasocket to do async http req.

But I want to use UDP from luasocket.
UDP receive() method from luasocket is blocking until it receives a message.

Corona SDK doesn't support LuaLanes.
So it's quite impossible to listen udp message in another thread.

So I'm just thinking if there's any method/trick/workaround in lua to detect and cancel if a function, in this case udp.receive(), is taking too long to respond?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the upd timeout?

See http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/udp.html at the bottom of the page.

Comment: you could use this timeout and some coroutine based wrapper to do other things in the mean time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.. Coroutines and events.. 
http://www.lua.org/pil/9.4.html

Fire a timer event that say calls a function every 100msec.. In that function resume a coroutine..

In the coroutine. You can read the incoming data in a loop and yield if not complete.

The example explains this well..

Good luck.. F.